# If every element of a subset is strictly smaller than the ones of another, what is the relation between their bounds?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose S is  a  set  with  the  least-upper-bound  property  and  the  greatest-lower-bound  property.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be subsets where every $x \in X$ and every $y\in Y$ is such that $x < y$.
I'm asked to show that $\sup{X} < \inf{Y}$ or provide a counterexample where this is doesn't hold.

I've previously showed that when $x\leq y$ for every $x\in X$ and $y \in Y$ we have that $\sup{X} \leq \inf{Y}$. It feels as if a similar proof employing strict inequalities should do the trick or this there some subtility with changing the inequalilties that breaks everything.
Or is there a simple counterexample that one can employ?

Comment: Hint: try some intervals of real numbers.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your previous result still obviously holds, that is, $\sup X \le \inf Y$. However, this inequality cannot be made strict.

A natural counterexample is to take $S = \Bbb R$, $X = (-\infty, 0)$, and $Y = (0, \infty)$.
Every negative number is strictly less than every positive number but the supremum and infimum coincide.

Even more natural might be to take $S$ and $X$ as above but $Y = \{0\}$.

---

**Some more details**

A more intuitive way to think is that even though you have $x < y$ for all $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$, you can choose the numbers to be "arbitrarily close".

In fact, this is something usual: you don't expect strict inequality to hold in inequalities involving $\sup$ and $\inf$.
For example, suppose you have $s \in S$ such that $x < s$ for all $x \in X.$ Even then you cannot conclude that $\sup X < s$.

Comment: This is a really helpful explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$S=\mathbb{R}$, $X=[0,1)$ and $Y=(1,2]$.

Comment: Of course. Its always something obivous! Thanks a bunch!